# How to iterate over UIImageView and assigning each element with UIImage in Swift?

Tags: swift, xcode, for-loop, uiimageview, uiimage

I want to create array of UIImageView with icons as an image, then I want to place them into stackView as [arrangedSubViews], I have tried to create them manually and hard coded, but even that not working? How can I achieve that? Please any way is appreciated.

Here is how i am trying to hard code them even it not worked.

```
    var icons = [#imageLiteral(resourceName: "user"), #imageLiteral(resourceName: "lock"), 
      #imageLiteral(resourceName: "lock"), #imageLiteral(resourceName: 
     "user"),#imageLiteral(resourceName: "eys")]


    var iconImageViews = [UIImageView]()
    
    
    for n in 0...4 {
        iconImageViews[n].image = icons[n]
        iconImageViews[n].heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true
        iconImageViews[n].widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true
    }
```

[image: here is i have tried manually and using loop, but no working]

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
var icons = [#imageLiteral(resourceName: "user"), #imageLiteral(resourceName: "lock"), 
  #imageLiteral(resourceName: "lock"), #imageLiteral(resourceName: 
 "user"),#imageLiteral(resourceName: "eys")]


var iconImageViews = [UIImageView]()


icons.forEach {
    let imgView = UIImageView()
    imgView.image = $0
    imgView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    imgView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true
    imgView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true
    iconImageViews.append(imgView)
}
```

Comment: Yeah yeahpp bro, thank you so much, it worked